# How do I see my file after the CKAN DCAT plug-in has consumed it

Tags: ckan, dcat

I have consumed a turtle file into the CKAN dcat plugin extension via command line like so

```
python ckanext-dcat/ckanext/dcat/processors.py consume glue.ttl -P -f  n3
```

Is there supposed to be some json output in response to this because I am not seeing any and if it did or does work how do I now pull up and see that file on the CKAN UI.